# Searching an array for combinations of values

Tags: matlab, match, combinations

This should be a fairly simple question to answer, but I am interested to hear some unique ways to do it, so here goes. I am using Matlab, but a viable C# solution would work for me as well.

I have an array (23000 rows x 3 columns). Each row is a combination of 3 values from a set of 90 values. I would like select a subset of these 90 values, say 10, and find the rows in which ANY 3 of these 10 values are members, and return the row number.

Now, I could generate a list of all the 3-value combinations of those 10 values, and then use `ismember` in Matlab to find the row for each combination. But is there a different or more elegant way?

Alternately, I could use `a=sum(ismember(array, 'value'),2)` to generate a logical vector where `'value'` occurs in `array`, and use `b=find(a)` to find the row indices where `'value'` occurs. I could do this for each value of the 10. But now the problem becomes, of these 10 lists of indices, which index occurs 3 or more times?

Any thoughts/comments/questions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: if c# simply iterate through the entire array checking each column against an array of 10 acceptable values.

Comment: So, you want rows where the value of all 3 columns are contained in the 10 possible values?

Comment: yes, tmpearce, that's correct. bkr, I'm relatively new to C#, but it's so much faster than Matlab, a solution there would be great (especially since I'm eventually writing an application using this code), but you may have to spell it out a little more for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost right with your suggestion of logical indexing.

Make value a vector with all the possible values:

```
value = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
```

Now you can use ismember on all the values at once.

```
logical_array = ismember(array, value);
num_matches = sum(logical_array,2);
rows_with_3_matches = find(num_matches==3);
logical_vector = num_matches==3;
```

Comment: man, that was as simple as I was expecting. Thanks for taking the time to answer. Care to offer any insight on how to implement this in C#?