# Search SQL database and return rows whose columns containing specific values

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, search

UPDATED FOR CLARIFICATION

I posted a similar question a while back [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145486/searching-an-array-for-combinations-of-values) which used Matlab (and  Matlab GUI).

However, now I am trying to do the same thing, but implemented through a Windows Form, C#, and a local, static database file which has been populated with data already.

The data in the database is as follows:

```
Compound_ID    Component1    Component2    Component3    Value
int            string        string        string        int
```

with ~24,000 rows of data.

The first column "Compound_ID" is the primary key. The next three columns, "Component1", "Component2", and "Component3", contain one component each from a set of ~100 possible components. Each compound is made up of 3 different components from the set of 100. Order of components doesn't matter, so the Compounds are combinations (as distinct from permutations) of 3 components. Example:

```
Compound_ID    Component1    Component2    Component3    Value
1456           a            b              c             10
1457           a            b              m             50
1458           a            c              g             25
```

etc. From this example, we know that there will never be another compound in the DB that is "a g c" or any other permutation thereof, since order doesn't matter (A list of 100 values will generate ~161,000 combinations of 3, but almost 1,000,000 permutations of 3).

The user will select some number of components (with a list of checkboxes or a spreadsheet) on the Windows Form. They will press a button on the form. The button will call a method to find all of the Compounds listed in the database which can be made from the list of components the user has selected. This data will be displayed in a dataGridView on the same form.

One way it might be done (similar to the Matlab solution described by another user in my previous post): Generate 3 logical arrays, one for each column, where "1" represents the rows containing one of the 15 components. Add the columns together, and only those rows which have a value of "3" are the rows I am looking for. Then build a new table containing those rows, and display in datagridview. Any tips on how this code might look would be helpful.

I am going to give some of the solutions already provided a try. This would involve figuring out a way to call an SQL Query from C#, which I am told I can look up, and an example has already been provided.

Thanks to everyone for your help. This is a solely independent project born of curiosity, so it is not serious business, I am just trying to figure it out. I am relatively new to C# (and definitely SQL Queries), so please excuse my ignorance. Point me to sources with a little explanation if that would be a better use of everyone's time.

Comment: What database access technology are you using? What have you tried? Also, why don't you give you columns significant names?

Comment: Honestly this is where a NoSQL solution would be a much better fit.  The schema is killing you here...

Comment: Can `Col`, `Col2` and `Col3` all contain the same value, and thus be excluded from your results?

Comment: Danny Varod: I am not sure of the answer to that question. I guess SQL Server 2008? Where would I find that information?

Comment: Tim Schmelter: The data in col1 col2 col3 of the database contain a unique combination of values. I want to search for any **unique** combination. But searching for **any** combination would produce the same results, though it might take longer. Thanks for clarifying. 

rs_atl: I am new to C# and SQL. what is a NoSQL solution? 

col1 col2 col3 are a unique combination for a given row.

Comment: So dude, it looks like no one was able to arrive at an acceptable solution.  Try restating it more thoroughly so we can help you out.

Comment: This part is still confusing: I am looking for any/all rows which contain any combination (NOT PERMUTATION) of 3 of the 15 components. The rows do not contain duplicate values, and no row has the same combination as any other row.  How does the user select 3 out of the 15, and how are you select the 15 from the 100?

Comment: @GrayFox374 So like you said, I obviously didn't state my problem clearly enough, which explains why everyone is kind of fed up with me!  I am creating a Windows Form. The user will select components from a list of checkboxes. They will press a button. The button will call a method to search this (static, unchanging) database.  What will be returned is this: any row which contains (in col1, col2, and col3) 3 components from the ones they've selected. (cont.)

Comment: @GrayFox374 The rows in the database can be thought of as containing a compound, if you will, with the components being the ingredients of the compound. I want to find all the compounds contained in the database that I can make from the list of components selected.  Each compound is made up of three different components, in any order.  To clarify, not every combination of 3/100 components is a valid compound (that would be ~161,000 combos). There are other properties of these components which determine if they make valid compounds or not, but that is not important for the problem at hand.

Comment: This makes more sense.  I am working this now.  I think you have to fetch the entire result set once from the db, then parse it programmatically.

Comment: Oh great, thank you! I bet I can figure out the parsing on my own, so don't spend time doing that (unless it's more involved than I'm imagining...)

Comment: @GrayFox374 Hey I got it working. I posted the answer below. I used your C# code and the query from LittleBobbyTable. Thanks for you help and your patience! Did you end up coming up with something?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think this is it:

UPDATE

database table values

```
PKID    Col1        Col2        Col3        Cost 
1   Helium      Oxygen      Nitrogen    10
2   Hydrogen    Chlorine    Sodium      10 
3   Chlorine    Sodium      Gold        10
4   Hydrogen    Carbon      Potassium   10 
5   Carbon      Silicon     Boron       10
6   Uranium     Cesium      Plutonium   10 
7   Titanium    Iodine      Fluorine    10
8   Helium      Neon        Argon       10 
9   Krypton     Xenon       Radon       10
10  Barium      Chromium    Calcium     10 
11  Helium      Lithium     Sodium      10
```

So if you choose Helium, Oxygen, Nitrogen, Barium, Chromium, Calcium and Uranium, you should get rows with PKIDs 1 and 10, and that's it.  Right?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        List<Component> results = new List<Component>();

        foreach (object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            var cn = new OdbcConnection(@"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=C:\elements.mdb;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("SELECT [PKID], [Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Cost] ");
            sb.Append("FROM components ");
            sb.Append("WHERE ? IN (Col1, Col2, Col3) ");
            var cm = new OdbcCommand(sb.ToString(), cn);
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                cm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", itemChecked.ToString());
                OdbcDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        var comp = new Component(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString()),
                            dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString(), dr[3].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(dr[4].ToString()));

                        Component r = results.Find(
                            delegate(Component c)
                            {
                                return c.CompoundID == Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());
                            }
                            );
                        if (r != null)
                        {
                            //update the frequency
                            var obj = results.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CompoundID == comp.CompoundID);
                            if (obj != null) obj.Frequency++;
                        }
                        else { results.Add(comp); }
                    }
                }
                dr.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
            finally { cn.Close(); }
        }

        //process/present results at this point
        //for each result in list with freq >= 3, output to grid
        IEnumerable<Component> rowsWithThreeHits = results.Where(cFreq => int.Equals(cFreq.Frequency, 3))
            .Select(x => new Component { CompoundID = x.CompoundID, Component1 = x.Component1, 
                Component2 = x.Component2, Component3 = x.Component3, CompoundValue = x.CompoundValue });
        List<Component> final = new List<Component>(rowsWithThreeHits);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = final;
    }        
}

public class Component
{
    public int CompoundID { get; set; }
    public string Component1 { get; set; }
    public string Component2 { get; set; }
    public string Component3 { get; set; }
    public int CompoundValue { get; set; }
    public int Frequency { get; set; }

    public Component() {}

    public Component(int compoundID, string component1, string component2, string component3, int compoundValue)
    {
        CompoundID = compoundID; 
        Component1 = component1;
        Component2 = component2;
        Component3 = component3;
        CompoundValue = compoundValue;
        Frequency = 1;
    }
}
```

I used Access because we don't use SQL Server here, but you can swap out the ODBC object for SQL objects and it works.

[image: UI ScreenShot with Results]

Comment: How does this ensure that the row contains all three values?

Comment: Ok, so if we are looking for 'a', 'b', 'c', please add a row to the table that contains 'a', 'x', 'y'. Your query returns this row. Do you think it should? The OP also suggested they are looking for THREE components. Your query only allows for one to be specified.

Comment: I am looking for any/all rows which contain any combination (NOT PERMUTATION) of 3 of the 15 components. The rows do not contain duplicate values, and no row has the same combination as any other row.

Comment: Actually, he says "Lets say I've got a list of 15 components (of the possible 100)."  I think he meant that he is looking for the results of any of the 15 components in any of the 3 columns that have the string datatype, that's the only way it makes sense.  I said it the beginning that I didn't think he was very clear.  But if it is as you say, at what point are the 15 and the 100 relevant?  And mine allows for the iterating through all 15, against all 3 columns where a match might be stored.

Comment: You win. I deleted my unhelpful, hardcoded-to-death answer. Maybe your multiple-down-voted answer is more helpful after all. <shrug> Your SQL query still doesn't give the right answer, whether you wrap it with a bow in a nice C# package or not.

Comment: @AaronBertrand One way or the other, I appreciate your help. I came here because I either didn't know what I was looking for or didn't understand whatever results I had already found. I was hoping human minds would be better than scouring MSDN. Maybe I can implement other users' solutions (like yours) into this "nice C# package."

Comment: I may be wrong, and I asked the OP to try and do a better job of stating the issue, and I may delete mine or revise it as I understand it better.  You seem pretty testy.  No one is attacking you, least of all me.  Try not to be so hypersensitive.  This just goes to show why communication is so challenging.  We both read the question and interpreted it a little differently, like the 3 blind men examining the elephant.  I believe you made an honest stab at an answer, as did I.  No need to take your marbles and go home.

Comment: @GrayFox374 I'll offer you the same advice I offered the OP: use a little common sense when criticizing others. "Hard-coded to death" was completely unnecessary and frankly irrelevant to the problem. Just because you were the only person to bridge the (incorrect) query to C# does not make you the holiest of all helpful people and give you the right to tell anyone that their answer wasn't helpful.

Comment: It was AN EXAMPLE. I didn't realize that I would actually have to demonstrate how to use variables as part of the solution. I was focusing on THE QUERY.

Comment: Well I updated the post to try and clarify. Now it's a book. And I am going to give some solutions suggested here a try. Thanks to both of you for the help.

Comment: Hey this is great! More elegant than how I'm doing it atm. I am still getting the hang of best practices for creating and using custom classes (I first learned programming with Matlab...). I may steal yours, but I think I'll change the name to "compounds" rather than "components." Thanks again for the insight! This would've taken me ages to crank out, but I think I learned a lot more by looking through your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select ct.*
From costtable ct
Where ct.Col1 <> ct.Col2 and ct.Col2 <> ct.Col3 and
ct.Col1 in ('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3') and
ct.Col2 in ('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3') and
ct.Col3 in ('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3')
```

I'm not sure about your use case, but are duplicate components possible? like Col1 and Col2 with the same value?

Here is the SqlFiddle you can play with:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46944/1/0

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to SqlFiddle! Looks like a helpful learning tool. And your code does exactly what I want it to do, judging from me screwing around with the link you provided. I'll report back once it's up and running in my form.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this where @a, @b, @c are the values you seek

```
select 
*
from
table
where
(
case col1 when @a then 1 when @b then 2 when @c then 4 else 0 end
+ case col2 when @a then 1 when @b then 2 when @c then 4 else 0 end
+ case col3 when @a then 1 when @b then 2 when @c then 4 else 0 end
      ) = 7
```

Unlike a simplistic `IN` solution, this will assure uniqueness of combinations

Comment: FWIW my IN solution assures uniqueness of combinations as well, provided that the three values are distinct.

Comment: I don't really need uniqueness of combinations in the search, as the database does not contain rows with the same combination ( no "abc" and "bac"). But still, how do I implement this into my C# code?

Comment: @podiluska Thank you for your help. Sounds like this query would work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that ended up doing what I needed. It is a combination of [LittleBobbyTables's SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11512537/1470783) and [GrayFox374's C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11512561/1470783) to implement that query. I would upvote you both, but evidently I don't have the clout to do that yet!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> components = new List<string>();
        components.Add("Ing1");
        components.Add("Ing2");
        components.Add("Ing3");
        components.Add("Ing5");
        components.Add("Ing9");


        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        sb1.Append("(");

        foreach (string s in components)
        {
            string stemp = "'" + s + "'" + ",";
            sb1.Append(stemp);
        }

        int start = sb1.ToString().Length - 2;

        sb1.Replace(",", ")", start, 2);

        List<Result> results = new List<Result>();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\dbTestCSV.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("SELECT [Numbers], [Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4], [Col5]");
        sb.Append("FROM Table1 ");
        sb.Append("WHERE [Col1] IN ");
        sb.Append(sb1.ToString());
        sb.Append(" AND [Col2] IN ");
        sb.Append(sb1.ToString());
        sb.Append(" AND [Col3] IN ");
        sb.Append(sb1.ToString());

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), con);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    results.Add(new Result(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString()), dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString(), dr[3].ToString(), dr[4].ToString(), dr[5].ToString()));
                }
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }


        foreach (Result res1 in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(res1.PK.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
        //process/present results at this point

    }


}

public class Result
{
    public int PK { get; set; }
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public string Col2 { get; set; }
    public string Col3 { get; set; }
    public string Col4 { get; set; }
    public string Col5 { get; set; }

    public Result(int pk, string col1, string col2, string col3, string col4, string col5)
    {
        PK = pk; Col1 = col1; Col2 = col2; Col3 = col3; Col4 = col4; Col5 = col5;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been working on this, I have a couple issues, but I will post what I have so far.

Comment: @GrayFox374 Thanks! I appreciate the help. Don't spend any more time on it, I'll take it from here :) Your original code was a huge help. I think the key was passing the SQL commands and the datareader object.

Comment: I've got it, adding it to the gridview and everything.  I enjoyed the challenge and I learned something new.

Comment: Glad I could provide some impetus for creativity :)